# Is it safe to allow all read/write permissions using sever-side firebase-admin (realtime database) in production?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a web app in Python with the `firebase-admin` package using firebase's realtime database product based on a fairly simple concept. I'm scraping an XML API service at regular intervals and checking for updates in the data. If there is an update I'm alerting my users who do not need to be signed in or authenticated to get these updates.

I've been careful not to commit my private key (in the firebase json generated file) to source control and all the code is server-side. Is it a security risk to allow full read/write permissions in production such as using the Firebase rules below:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "true"
    }
}
```

As this use-case is fairly simple I could not find a definitive answer to this question elsewhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to esqew's excellent answer, you might want to consider that code that accesses Firebase through an Admin SDK already has full, administrative access to the Firebase project and **bypasses the security rules**.

So if only your Python code is interacting with the database, you can eliminate most of the risk by changing your rules to:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false
    }
}
```

With this simple change, users using either a client-side SDK or REST API won't have any access to the data.

---

If your end-users *do* need read-access, consider tweaking your rules to the minimum they need (the principle of least privilege that esqew also mentioned).

For example, if you have a node called `alerts` for your alerts, simply changing the rules to this will already improve security:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "alerts": {
            ".read": false
        },
        ".write": false
    }
}
```

With these rules a malicious user needs to already *know* that the `alerts` node exists, before they can access the data in it. And while this is not a strong barrier, it will help against the most common form of attach: malicious users just trying to read the root of your database.

Comment: I know stack overflow doesn't like me to add this in the comments, but thanks this is incredibly useful!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a security risk to allow full read/write permissions in production...?

### **Yes**

In production environments, generally speaking, you want to strive to adhere as closely as is practically possible to the [Principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege#:%7E:text=In%20information%20security%2C%20computer%20science,a%20user%2C%20or%20a%20program%2C). The linked article sums it up nicely:

> ... the principle of least privilege (PoLP)... requires that... every module (such as a process, a user, or a program, depending on the subject) must be able to access only the information and resources that are necessary for its legitimate purpose.

Again, generally speaking, there is almost never a use case which would require database-wide read/write access (except maybe for certain privileged daemons and the like).

While *you* yourself may now be actively taking steps to prevent the exposure of your private keys or other credential data that would be used, it doesn't account for future (realistic) attack scenarios where these credentials/keys are maliciously exfiltrated by someone internal, inadvertently committed to source control by other developers, or even extracted through vulnerabilities in your dependencies that are not currently widely known. In all the aforementioned scenarios, least-privilege limits the damage that these bad actors can inflict on your systems and data.

In short - you should only allow the access to tables/objects where it is **strictly necessary** for the code in question. Anything else constitutes largely unnecessary risk, especially in production-grade environments.